# Why is the x axis backwards and x and y axis not labeled in this simple scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

Why doesn't this simple scatter plot work in a sane way? It seems like I'm having to jump through hoops for something that ought to "just work". I think the code below should result in plot with (0,0) as the origin and an x and y axis that each go up to 10 with nicely labeled, evenly spaced tick marks on each axis. Instead, the origin is at 1,7 and the x axis is backwards, decreasing from right to left.

Maybe I'm going blind, but I've looked through the Tutorials and Gallery and I can't find any example of a plain, simple, no-frills plot of distinct points on a coordinate plane.

```
x = ['7', '8', '6', '7.5', '4']
y = ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3']
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10)
plt.show()
```

[image: Poorly labeled backwards scatter plot]

I have also tried

```
plt.plot(x,y, 'ro')
plt.axis([0,10,0,10])
plt.show()
```

with similar results.
[image: Another poorly labeled backwards plot]

I've been able to get sane looking results by calling `plt.gca().invert_xaxis()` to get the x axis into an increasing rather than decreasing direction and manually passing a list of tickmarks to xticks and yticks, but I don't understand why that's necessary. Why doesn't setting the max and min for the x and y axis result in a graph with sensible default tick marks?

Comment: `plt.scatter([float(xi) for xi in x], [float(yi) for yi in y], ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lists are of strings, not numbers so matplotlib doesn't really know how to handle them in the way that you expect. Remove the single quotes from the x and y lists and try it again.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't catch that. The data isn't actually in my script, I just printed it to copy/paste into this question rather than including the code that's reading in the data. It's a pity that matplotlib doesn't throw an exception instead of just plotting garbage. I assumed the problem was that I didn't know how to use matplotlib, not that my source data was in the wrong format. I would have solved this hours ago if it had just told me "I can't plot strings, dummy!"